# How to set the current working directory in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-io, working-directory

In a dart console application, how do I set the current working directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';
... 
Directory.current = new Directory('your/path/here');
```

or just

```
Directory.current = 'your/path/here';
```

See also https://api.dartlang.org/133671/dart-io/Directory/current.html

Comment: Current link: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.2/dart-io/Directory/current.html